# Перевод строчки в целое число

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда я преобразую значение переменной в целое число, и потом проверяю эту переменную на отсутствия значения `if (s == null)`, то не получается, а получается, когда так `if (!s)`. Почему если значение `null` входит в правило лжи таким вот `if (s == null)` способом, не получается?

```
var s = prompt("Угадайте число", "");
s = parseInt(s);
if (s == null) 
     document.write("Пусто");
else
     document.write("OK");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Поэтому](http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/Qr2wh/).
Возвращает NaN.

Comment: @ReinRaus но почему var s не могу проверить на отсутствие значения ?

Comment: Мб вы на танке?..

Comment: @AlexWindHope такая запись тоже не работает: `if (s == NaN)`.
Если мои вопросы странные, то объясните, потому что я недавно начал изучать JS.

Comment: [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = prompt("Угадайте число", "");
if (!isNaN(s)) {
    alert("Ок");
}
```

Выведет Ок всякий раз, когда будет введено число.

Значение выражения не может быть проверено на NaN иначе, как с помощью функции isNaN. Значение null говорит, что выражение имеет тип объекта, при этом объект не существует.